# normalize data to scale from 1 to 10

Tags: excel, normalization

I have a following data set:

```
A   B   N
1   3   10
2   3   5
3   3   1
3   6   5
10  10  1
20  41  5
20  120 9
```

I'm looking for an excel function that will normalize A and B to N on scale from 1 to 10.

In above example it would be

```
1 of 3 is best so N = 10
2 of 3 is in the middle N = 5
3 of 3 is worst N=1
20 of 120 is in second decade N=9
```

A >= 1 && A <= B

B is natural number

1 <= N <= 10

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "normalize A and B to N on scale from 1 to 10".

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to explain what you're trying to do in a much more systematic way if you want to get an answer.

Comment: From A and B I want to calculate N. Above are some examples.

Comment: For a 1-d situation, you simply find the min and max, and do some division.  But you have this "best" and "worst" thing going on, can you flesh that out?

Comment: Trying to guess what you mean, it seems that you're trying to compute the value N already in the data set from the values of A and B in the same column, such that N specifies on a scale from 1 to 10 where A is on a scale from 1 to B. However, in the first three rows N is decreasing with increasing A, whereas for the last row you're saying N=2 because 20 of 120 is in the second "decade" (I presume you mean a tenth of the scale?). But according to the example of the first three rows, then N should be around 9, not 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposing your numbers are in cols A and B. Write at c1:

```
=MAX(CEILING((B1-A1)/(B1-1)*10,1),1)
```

And drag to the bottom of column C

Comment: Very good except this produces answers for N = 10, 5, 1, 6, 1, 6, 9 which doesn't quite match the sample values in the OP.  However it meets the intent.  Other problem is a #DIV/0! error at the degenerate edge case of A = B = 1

Answer (score 2):

You should use the trend function.....I don't know how good you really at solving equations but here is goes

Use trends function in excel.....

trends( Y set of values, x set of values, new x set of values, true)

now specify scale 1 and 10 in Y set of values

for  x set of values specify  B and 0

and then for new x set of values specify value that you want to normalize

A   B
20   120

B =120

since it works on y=mx + c

(x1,y1) = (120,0)
and (x2,y2) = (0,10)

any new x that you enter will be normalized on basis of this

so if I enter 20 in new x, then my answer will be **8.333** not 9 (it is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

`10*(Cell-MIN(Range))/(MAX(Range))-MIN(Range))`. The question was really very simple. He has data that's not in the range of 1-10...and he wants the highest value to be equal to 10, and the lowest to be equal to 1, with the other values normalized between them.

"cell" is the actual cell where you are putting in the formula. The range is the data to be normalized.

Comment: This normalizes to a range of 0-10, not 1-10.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is "lower the better" try this Column D1 and drag down

```
1+(A1-MIN(A$1:A$7))*(0-10)/(MAX(A$1:A$7)-MIN(A$1:A$7)))
```